# Azure App Service - Get Stack settings via API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-rest-api

I have a lot of webapps with different stack settings:
[image]

And I'm trying to automate getting that data.
I've tried az cli webapp, and webapp/webapp settings/webapp appsettings rest api endpoints, but I can't find it anywhere.
There are some keys like:

```
{...
  "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
  "nodeVersion": "",
  "numberOfWorkers": 1,
  "phpVersion": "5.6",
  "preWarmedInstanceCount": 0,
  "push": null,
  "pythonVersion": ""
...}
```

But the result is inconclusive - it shows php and netframework versions.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you select the `PHP` with version `5.6` in the portal -> Save, then select back to `.Net` -> Save, you will find the `phpVersion` is always `5.6` by getting the settings of the web app as you mentioned.

If you just want to get the stack setting used currently, you could use the REST API below.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<webapp-name>/config/metadata/list?api-version=2020-06-01
```

It will give the response like below, you can get the `"CURRENT_STACK": "dotnet"`.

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxxx/config/metadata",
  "location": "Central US",
  "name": "metadata",
  "properties": {
    "CURRENT_STACK": "dotnet"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "xxxx",
  "tags": {},
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
}
```

But this API will not return the detailed version, so your option is to use it with something like `az webapp config show` or other getting webapp setting method together.

If you want to use this API in azure cli, you could use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest):

```
az rest --method post --uri https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<webapp-name>/config/metadata/list?api-version=2020-06-01
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that works, the properties key is empty, tested this on dotnet, PHP and python webapps.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listconfigurations
On this endpoint there are linuxFXversion and windowsFXVersion keys in properties, but the windowsFXVersion is always None, even for windows webapps. For Linux it contains all the nesseccary information, ex:
'linuxFxVersion': 'PYTHON|3.6'
But I have quite a few of the windows webapps to get the info from...

Comment: @Ratiel There are some differences between windows and linux apps, for windows app, my solution will work, for linux app, just check `LinuxFxVersion` directly.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm saying - it's not working for windows apps, the properties key that should contain CURRENT_STACK is empty.

Comment: @Ratiel I test it with Windows app, it works, as shown in my screenshot.

Comment: Yea, you're example is showing the property. I've tested this on several hundred of my windows webapps, and the property key is mostly empty. Sometimes there's stack value, and sometimes there's some VSTSRM settings. But for 90% of time - empty.

Comment: @Ratiel Well, it is so weird.